# Freemarker alternative[syntax] if condition with number

Tags: freemarker

I am using alternative freemarker syntax(the one with square brackets). It works fine but I am not able to figure out how to use if condition to check if a number is greater than or less than. Following is the syntax I have

```
[#if ${numberCoupons} <= 1]
    [#assign couponsText = 'coupon']
[/#if]
```

Here "<" symbol fails. Do you know what am I doing wrong here.

Also is there any documentation for list of entire directives that can be used with alternative syntax of freemarker?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should be able to use any of the following:

```
[#if (numberCoupons <= 1)]
[#if numberCoupons &lt;= 1]
[#if numberCoupons lte 1]
[#if numberCoupons \lte 1]
```

I would use the parens.

This is detailed at:
http://freemarker.sourceforge.net/docs/dgui_template_exp.html#dgui_template_exp_comparison

Scroll down just a little to the last paragraph in that section that starts with "There is a little problem"

Answer (score 0):

In this case the error message should complain about the `{`, not the `<`. Are you looking at the good place? Anyway, you can't use `${...}` there. It should be simply `[#if numberCoupons <= 1]`.

Comment: I changed to as per what you have said, but its still giving me same error

Comment: I guess you aren't looking at the place where the error is. I assume you have used the line number from the error message, so maybe it's in another template then.